# insert data with comma delimiter but with different ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Hi I am having a problem with my **bulk insertion.**
The challenge/objective is to save a column with comma delimiter to another table with different ID's
like for example->
I selected query
 from @temp table

> Rolln                       FullName
>   441246                   John Doe, Jane More, John Spade
>   441248                   Jose Mendez, Ali Muhm, Jacob Stile

to be save in People table
The result would be after insertion to People->

> People_ID                    RollNumber               FullName
>   1                                   441246                      John Doe
>   2                                   441246                      Jane More
>   3                                   441246                      John Spade

my script that I created is repeating the name

```
INSERT @Temp_Original
select rollnumber,
case when CHARINDEX(',',FullName)>0 
     then SUBSTRING(FullName,1,CHARINDEX(',',FullName)-1) 
     else FullName end FullName, 
CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(',',FullName)>0 
     THEN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(FullName,CHARINDEX(',',FullName)+1,len(FullName)), ',', '') 
     ELSE NULL END as FullName2,
 CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(',',FullName)>0 
     THEN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(FullName,CHARINDEX(',',FullName)+1,len(FullName)), ',', '')  
     ELSE NULL END as FullName3,
[Address], Code, Place, [Country], LegalTxt
from (
select newrec.RollNumber, newrec.FullName, newrec.[Address], newrec.Code, newrec.Place, newrec.Country, newrec.LegalTxt
 from [dbo].[view_FinanceCompare] newrec
left join [dbo].[view_MainCompare] oldrec
on newrec.RollNumber = oldrec.rollnumber
where  oldrec.rollnumber is null
) t



--Print 'Insert to people'
Insert [dbo].[dbo_People] ([FullName], [CreatedOn], [CreatedBy])
Select Fullname, getdate(), rollnumber
From @Temp_Original
UNION 
Select Fullname2, getdate(), rollnumber
From @Temp_Original Where FullName2<>''
UNION 
Select Fullname3, getdate(), rollnumber
From @Temp_Original Where FullName3<>''
```

Your helping hand is mostly appreciated.

Comment: do not do this in sql

Comment: @Ewan is partly correct.  You can do it in SQL, but your People_ID must be excluded as your contacts or People/Contact Table in your Database probably has it's own indexed ID.

Comment: @Leptonator the People_id is auto increment(int)/seeding

Comment: i think you will find i am FULLY correct!! (in my ideological statement) :) but I'm guessing this is homework and the answer must be some compex non -scalable dynamic sql mess

Comment: @Ewan its not a homework.. I am creating a script for bulk uploading

Comment: well in that case let me expand on my terse comment! attempting to do this kind of transform in an sql query is inherently difficult and problematic. However if you do the splitting logic in whatever app is calling the sql db, its simple to create individual insert statements which will match your needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with recursive cte. Here is example:

```
create table t(id int, n nvarchar(max))
Insert into t values
(1, 'a,b,c'),
(2, 'e,f,g')

; with cte as (
  Select 
  Id,
  N,
  substring(n, 1, charindex(',', n)-1) as name,
  Charindex(',',n) as p
  From t

  Union all

  Select id, n, substring(n, p+1, charindex(',', n, p)-1),
  Charindex(',', n, p+1)
  From cte
  Where p <> 0
)

Select id, namename from cte
Order by id, name
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/449bc/2